# How to tell which assembler instructions are obsolete?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, instructions, obsolete

I'm reviewing my assembly language skills since it's been a while that I've touched that subject. I recently read that instructions like BCD instructions (`AAA`, `AAD`, `AAM`, `AAS`, etc.) and floating-point instructions (`FLD`, `FST`, etc.) aren't commonly used anymore or shouldn't be used or are literally obsolete in modern x86-64 assembler.

Where can I get a complete reference on which instructions are obsolete or shouldn't be used in favor of better newer ones?
Else, is there a modern assembler reference which purposefully only treats of relevant instructions in x86-64 assembler?

Comment: The official instruction set reference of course lists instructions that are no longer supported. That covers the BCD instructions in 64 bit mode. The FPU instructions are still supported, and useful for things such as transcendental functions and extended precision. Also, the optimization manual gives hints about instructions to avoid.

Comment: Page 6+ of this Agner Fog document shows which instructions have been added as processors evolved as well lists which instructions were removed in 64-bit long mode: http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Comment: The BCD instructions were pretty much obsolete on anything post-8088, unless by "obsolete" you mean "unsupported", in which case, the Intel documentation and Agner Fog's manuals would answer that question. To determine what instructions are commonly used in modern assembly programming, you'd basically look at the output of a modern C or C++ compiler. Although the x87 FPU instructions can still be used in certain cases, they've been almost 100% replaced by SSE2 instructions on x86-64, or newer instruction sets like AVX. Most everything else is still around and kicking. Backwards-compatibility!